# jQuery grep is skipping terms in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex

I am trying to filter an array of strings using the [jQuery grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) function, but it is skipping the elements in the array. If I debug through the code all the conditions are returning true, but if I run the code without debugging it is skipping the second element.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery.grep demo</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p></p>
<script>
var arr = [ { value : "A1-99-101"}, { value : "A1-99-102"}, { value : "A1-99-109" } ];
var regex = /(?=.*?\bA1.*\b).*/ig;
var newarr = jQuery.grep(arr, function( n, i ) {
return (regex.test(n.value));
});
var printarr = '';
for (var i = 0; i < newarr.length; ++i) {
  printarr += newarr[i].value + ',';
}
$( "p" ).text( printarr );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an issue because of `g` modified in your regexp (`.../ig`). It forces regular expression to continue from last matched position. Here is what is happening:

- regexp matches to `A1-99-101` and saves position at 0
- next iteration it moves position to 1, but doesn't match `A1-99-102`
- then regexp resets itself, because it reached end of the string
- and at last it matches third element `A1-99-109`

To fix this just remove `g` modifier:

```
var regex = /(?=.*?\bA1.*\b).*/i;
```

Also here is link to fiddle with [working code](http://jsfiddle.net/KcmrT/).

**Edit**

Also your regexp looks too complicated to me. If you just want to filter strings starting with `A1`, then use following regexp:

```
var regex = /A1/i;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ivan! And the reason I am using that regex is because I want to find all the string where 'A1' appears anywhere in the string.

Comment: If you want `A1` to match in any place, then `/A1/i` will do the job.